# Issues with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure what is wrong i am doing

Here is the JOIN i have

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on 
            table1.fkID = table2.fkID
            where table2.fkID= 500 order by 1 desc
```

i should multiple records but i am only getting 1, am i doing something wrong here

Comment: please provide sample data. It makes the ask more clearer

Comment: Side Note: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). This could especially problematic considering you are using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the condition in the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
select *
from table1 left outer join
     table2
     on table1.fkID = table2.fkID and
        table2.fkID= 500
 order by 1 desc;
```

The `where` clause filters out `NULL` values turning the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: its giving me so many recordsnow